# ValueError: too many values to unpack-python 2.7

Tags: python, nltk

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
from textblob import TextBlob
train = []
infile = open('bt2.txt','r')
for line in infile:
   train.append(line.strip().split(','))
infile.close()
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
blob = TextBlob('Explain the advantages', classifier=cl)
print(blob.classify())
```

this is my source code.bt2.txt contains almost 200 lines of comma seperated string and label.I'm getting following error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-21-72fecccf89d9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/xxx/bt.py', wdir='C:/Users/xxx')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/xxx/bt.py", line 12, in <module>
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 205, in __init__
    super(NLTKClassifier, self).__init__(train_set, feature_extractor, format, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 139, in __init__
    self._word_set = _get_words_from_dataset(self.train_set)  # Keep a hidden set of unique words.
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 63, in _get_words_from_dataset
    return set(all_words)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    all_words = chain.from_iterable(tokenize(words) for words, _ in dataset)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

How to solve this problem??

Comment: Show the full error with trace. The code on the error isn't in the code you provided.

Comment: I have edited my question.Please find full error with trace

Answer (score 1):

The NaiveBayesClassifier class **take a list of tuple with two elements** in it looks like you are having more than two elements.

**The error:**

```
all_words = chain.from_iterable(tokenize(words) for words, _ in dataset)
```

looks for two elements in dataset (words & _)

**Check if train[0] is two elements**

**[From the DOCS:](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html)**

```
train = [
     ('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
     ('this is an amazing place!', 'pos')]
```